# NavigationService.Navigate Throwing NullReferenceException WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

Just Downloaded the WP7 SDK yestarday - And I'm new to Silver light - and Application development in general.

I'm just simply trying to Direct my user to a different page, but I have a NullRefernceException Error occur on a Line Of Code. 
The Stupid thing - the code above it is exactly the same - yet doesn't throw the error?

```
if (myISO.DirectoryExists("Logs") && myISO.DirectoryExists("DataStore"))
{
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Sign-in.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
else
{
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Welcome.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
     //Above Line Causes Exception^
}
```

Also I get an NullRefernceException in App.xaml.cs - which I haven't even changed - it WAS working - now it doesn't :

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Comment: What happens if you prefix your page names with a forward slash "/"? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Do you really have `Welcome.xaml` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

where is your **"/"** ?

Comment: Still - Doesn't work - It's down to calling it in the Constructor. Yet I Do't know where else to put it?

Comment: OK Starting to REALLY Piss me off. it's in it's own separate function now - Getting called from an OnClick event and still it's throwing a NullRefernceException - it's exactly the same as the other one - just copied and pasted with your Correction as well.

Comment: :( if possible, upload your small demo on filesharing sites ! i'll download and debug it :P

Comment: Oh- it's all right now - I just Reinstalled everything and created a new project. I have it in the OnNavigateTo() function which I overrided for that pages. My apologies if my last comment was a little aggressive. I was fed up at that point. :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug and identify which part of line throws an exception?

Also if you use NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Welcome.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); with "/" make sure that Welcome.xaml page is located in a root directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

```
This problem occurs after you change the Assembly Name or Namespace in 
Project Properties.
```

To fix it, Delete all contents of the Bin and obj Folders and recompile. see this [thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/92129/552104.aspx).

Also this is probably the reason why it worked when you created a new project.